# Need help on what to use for CefSharp Ajax Handler

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have a button called search, when I click it it will make an AJAX request and it will fetch me some data,
How can I write an event handler function that will run when AJAX is loaded completely? i.e For example once all the search result is displayed I need to do something in that handler function.

Answer (score 0):

This is just accessing an array (or an object) by index (or key). Nothing specific to jQuery.

In your case, you get a list of DOM elements from your selector, so `[0]` gives you the first one.